# How should I handle very large projections in an event-sourcing context?

Tags: event-sourcing

I wanted to explore the implications of event-sourcing v.s. active-record.

Suppose I have events with *payloads* like this:

```
{
  "type": "userCreated", 
  "id": "4a4cf26c-76ec-4a5a-b839-10cadd206eac", 
  "name": "Alice", 
  "passwordHash": "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824"
}
```

... and...

```
{
  "type": "userDeactivated", 
  "id": "39fd0e9a-1025-42e6-8793-ed5bfa236f40"
}
```

I can reach the current state of my system with a reducer like this:

```
const activeUsers = new Map();

for (const event of events) {

  // userCreated
  if (event.payload.type == 'userCreated') {
    const { id, name, passwordHash } = event.payload;
    if (!activeUsers.has(id)) {
      activeUsers.set(id, { name, passwordHash });
    }
  }

  // userDeactivated
  if (event.payload.type == 'userDeactivated') {
    const { id } = event.payload;
    if (activeUsers.has(id)) {
      activeUsers.delete(id);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I cannot have my *entire* user table in a single `Map`.

So it seems I need a reducer for each user:

```
const userReducer = id => // filter events by user id...
```

But this will lead to slow performance because I need to run a reducer over all events for each new user.

I could also *shard* the users by a function of their id:

```
const shard = nShards => id => {
  let hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (this.length === 0) {
    return hash;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    chr   = this.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0; // Convert to 32bit integer
  }
  return hash % nShards;
};
```

Then the maps will be less enormous.

How is this problem typically solved in event-sourcing models?

Comment: Events express facts that have happened in the past. So `createUser` should be `userCreated` or `userWasCreated`. The term `createUser` is more like a command, something that will be done.

Comment: What do you mean by "event-sourcing models"? The write/command models from the CQRS?

Comment: From where did you get the term `reducer`?

Comment: `reducer` is a term from `redux`. It is also common in the FP world. You might prefer `fold`.

Comment: By "event-sourcing models" I mean data models where you store events (what happened) and use those to compute the current system state. This is contrasted to active-record models whree you store only the current state and mutate it.

Comment: It seems like your problem has nothing to do with event-sourcing itself. Also, it is language specific. So, the question should be “How do I update a lot of entities checking their existence in memory?”, specifying particular language, DB and some little context. Also, I can assume that all events are strongly ordered by time, so you cannot deactivate a deleted user; implying this, there is no reason to check their existence. If this could happen — it's another question.

Comment: This question _is_ about event-sourcing. If you use an active-record model, then reading off a user's current state is easy (e.g. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ...`) but in an event-sourcing context you need to build this yourself from the events that you have received. The JavaScript was just to illustrate the point; it could equally be shown in another language. You are correct that events are strongly ordered on time.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you think you need to replay all the events using a reducer in order to query all the users, correct?

This is where cqrs comes into play together with `read models/denormalizers`.

What almost everyone does is they have a read model (which for example is stored in a sql database or something else which is good at querying data). this read model is constantly being updated when new events are created.

When you need to query all users you query this read model and not replay all events.